# Email is invalid ,user instance is invalid while trying to create user in loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm trying to create new user in loopback,but it is throwing error user instance is not valid and email is invalid. ('The `user` instance is not valid. Details: `email` is invalid)

newUser= { email: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
  password: 'xxxxxx',  name: 'Jyoti',  facebookId: 'xxxxxxxx',
  facebookToken:
   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  mobile: 'xxxxxxxxxx' }

```
User.create(newUser, function(err, nUser) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error",err);
    } else {
        console.log("db response",nUser);
    }
  });
```

Comment: What is the definition of `User`?

Comment: @DavidKnipe User is basically user model having fields name,email,password,facebookId,facebppkToken,mobile etc.

Comment: Show us the code where `User` is defined.